# Calling a Function in PHP file, using AJAX, with an ID specific to a record in Database to update record

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following html code that has embedded PHP

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (!$row['archived']) {
            echo "<tr id='" . $row['request_id'] . "'>
```

...

```
<button class='btn btn-warning archive'>Archive</button></br>
```

I have built the following JavaScript File

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    $(".archive").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../_php/functions.php',
            data: {'archive': $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')},
            success: function() {
                window.alert("done");
            },
            error: function() {
                window.alert("could not update");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am building my "functions" with this php file for data managment

```
<?php
    require "connect.php"; // get connected to database. 

    $archive = "UPDATE requests SET archived='1' WHERE request_id='$id'";
    if ($_POST['function'] == 'archive') {
        if ($conn->query($archive) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record " . $id . " has been archived.";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
        }
    } else if ($_POST['function'] == 'view') {

    }
?>
```

I have tested this out and I am expecting it to show me the success message and also change the respective record's "archived" value from 0 to 1 (or from false to true). I see the success message but my record continues to persist on the screen even after refreshing it and my database does not reflect the change from false to true (or from 0 to 1). I am wondering if I am missing something.

Comment: A note: instead of using the html attribute `id`, you might consider using a data attribute, like `data-request-id`. That gives the data a label of sorts, and avoids the possibility of a duplicate (example: you were showing two different lists of two different things on the same page) -- there can only technically be one element on a page with the same `id`, but many can have the same data attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not using the `id` which was passed with ajax is not properly used on `functions.php`. You are actually passed the `request_id` as `archive` but you are not using it.

in your code `$archive = "UPDATE requests SET archived='1' WHERE request_id='$id'"` but `$id` is not defined.

```
<?php
        require "connect.php"; // get connected to database. 


        /* make sure that archive button is clicked */
        if (isset($_POST['archive']) ) {
            /* Get the id here*/
            $id = $_POST['archive'];
            $archive = "UPDATE requests SET archived='1' WHERE request_id='$id'";
            if ($conn->query($archive) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record " . $id . " has been archived.";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
            }
        } else if ($_POST['function'] == 'view') {

        }
    ?>
```

Also inspect your network with inspection tools , so that you can check what response you get back from `functions.php. Also check console for any javascript error.

Comment: Also had to move "require connect.php" into the function for some reason . .  saw taht $conn was not be a valid variable according to profiler and so moved it inside after making those changes and SHAZAM! Archived record.

Comment: This uses unsantized data from the request. A better method would be to use parameters for the variable.

Comment: @ChrisBaker absolutely.. :-)

Comment: So I am lost, its early in the morning for me Chris, so can you let me know what you meant by use parameters for the variable?

Answer (score 0):

Change,

```
if ($_POST['function'] == 'archive')
```

To,

```
if ($_POST['archive'] == 'archive') {
```

As the `key` in your request is `{'archive': $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')},` and not `function`.

Comment: Maybe I should have been more productive. Why did you think that would work? Because it may help my thinking in the future.